# Is access checked at compile time or run time?

Tags: java, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JVM/Java, are method accessibility rules enforced at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088921/jvm-java-are-method-accessibility-rules-enforced-at-runtime)

When using a class that has both public and private fields and members, is the code checked for access violations (e.g. trying to access a private field from an outside class) at compiled time or run time? Or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both. If you try to compile code which tries to access inaccessible object or method, you'll get compile-time error:

```
field has private access in package.Class
```

Also, when your class tries to access some field at runtime, JVM checks the access:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field package.Class.field from class YourClass
```

Comment: So it is true that access information is stored in class files?

Comment: Yeap. For example see field_info structure: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5

Comment: You can change access of method run time with reflection API.
Here is the sample code. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-access-a-private-method-in-Java

Answer (score 3):

It is checked during compile time. I've tried the following two classes:

```
class A { 
    private int i;
}
```

and

```
class B { 
    private void test() {
        A a = new A();
        a.i = 5;
    }   
}
```

When I try to compile `B.java`, the following error occurs:

```
B.java:4: i has private access in A
        a.i = 5;
         ^
1 error
```

However, keep in mind that this simple example only works in the basic cases. This behaviour may change when reflection is considered, i.e., the name of the variable is only determined at runtime. In that case it is not possible to check the access modifier at compile-time and the check would have to be deferred to runtime.

Comment: Although all of those reflection methods, `getField()`, `getMethod()`, ect. do force you to deal with that possibility because they throw checked exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases. It is simple to see at compile time. But it's not difficult to test at runtime too. Create 2 classes

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test2.hello();
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

compile and run `java Test1`, it works OK

Now change Test2 as

```
priivate static void hello() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

and compile it separately, so that Test1.class is unchanged. Run `java Test1`. You will get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method Test2.hello()V from class Test1
    at Test1.main(Test1.java:5)
```